# Method Call when section of table View changed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with several sections. Now, I want to call a method with the section when the user changes the section with scrolling (user stopped scrolling in new section).
Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITableView` is a `UIScrollView`. Its `UIScrollViewDelegate` provides `-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` which you can use to detect when the view has stopped scrolling. The table view itself provides `-indexPathsForVisibleRows` which will then allow you to determine which section(s) have cells currently visible.

Comment: Unfournately this doesn't work for me. I implemented the scrollview delegate in the .h file and the scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation Methode but I don't see the tableview calling the methode. Is there anything else to set up?

Edit: It works perfectly! I had to earse derived data! Thank you!